# Autolayout Top Spacing not working

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout, uistoryboard, nslayoutconstraint

In my iOS app, I want a scrollView to appear a set distance away from the bottom of a UIImageView.

I tried defining this in my Storyboard as follows:

[image]

But in my app, it appears like this:

[image]

You can see from the above image that the ScrollView is cut off.  Is there a constraint that I'm missing?

**Edit:** Thanks for pointing out that there was an extraneous view - I removed it, but my scrollView is still not a set distance away from the bottom of the UIImageView (see updated images).

Comment: @bhavin I updated the view

Comment: If you click on the red arrow on the left menu it will tell you which constraints are conflicting. That is likely the cause of the issue. Posting that would help provide an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your `UIScrollView` is a child of another `UIView`. What are the constraints for that `UIView`?

Try setting the Top Space constraint between the parent `UIView` of the `UIScrollView` and the `UIImageView` instead of the `UIScrollView` and `UIImageView`.

Comment: I removed the extraneous UIView, but I am still experiencing the same problem.

Comment: The cause is likely due to your layout constraints being ambiguous (the red arrow). Could you post a screenshot of the conflicting constraints?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I set this constraints work in all orientation

For ImageView and UIScrollView
Pin->Leading,Trailing,Top,Bottom

Height constraints for both UIImageView and UIScrollView

For UIImageView i set height constraint priority high(750)